# communication beween distributed systems in erlang

Tags: linux, erlang

i have one master-controller(p.c) and other slave monitor(sensor) devices distributed in 1km of distance and connected through LAN.all are running erlang in that.controllers needs data of all sensors to displays for user(supervisor). right now i am trying to send data from sensors to controller using RPC. is it best method to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Erlang nodes--the master and slaves--clustered then you can use normal message passing between processes. If you haven't got them clustered--maybe the connection between master and slaves is not stable--RPC is fine, or you might even make a generic TCP network protocol.

If RPC is working for you, it's probably going to keep doing so.